# How to get Serial # from Symbol MC 3000 or any Symbol device

Tags: c#, serial-number

How to get Serial # from Symbol MC 3000 or any Symbol device?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, too. There does not seem to be an API for that (at least not in the Symbol SDK). There are ways to get the device ID using the Windows API (I don't have links right now, but you may want to google for Windows Mobile Device ID), but they never returned the S/N as printed on the device/the sticker on the device's box.

EDIT: Here's a link to MSDN sample code:
[Retrieving the Windows CE Device ID with the Microsoft .NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446562.aspx)